# How to recolor an image on specific area?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm trying to create an iOS recoloring app ([this is my reference](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/recolor-coloring-book-for/id1027352017)), and i need to know how recolor some portion of the image when user taps on a given area. All the loaded pictures will be black/white initially.

Is there any prebuilt library? Or which graphics framework should i use?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The concept is called `flood fill` for you to start, there is a very good library [opencv](http://opencv.org/) you can try it, there are many references there, you can search.

Comment: Please See https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is adding/replacing the colour within a certain shape and edges are really important (as in the example) then you should be looking into vectorised drawing.
What this means is every shape in your image would have an actual object representation in your code, and you could easily interact with that object to do whatever you want (i.e. tap gestures to change colour, zoom etc.). 
This however, means that you can't simply use .jpeg images, and you need to use images in vector format, such as .svg or CorelDraw.

As a reference, check out [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit), which is an excellent library for working with SVG images.